# refrencing certain values in a list

Tags: python, json

I have the following json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "person 1",
        "phones": {
            "home": [
                "000-111-2222",
                "333-444-5555"
            ],
            "cell": "666-777-8888"
        }
    },
    {
        "phones": {
            "home": "123-456-7890"
        },
        "name": "person 2"
    }
]
```

If I load the file using with open, it saves the file as type list.  From what I have seen using open with, any json object will load as type dict but any json array will load as type list.

```
def get_json():
    file_name = raw_input("Enter name of JSON File: ")
    with open(file_name) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        return json_data
```

I'm trying to figure out how to access certain parts of the file, such as after loading the json if i wanted to print just the line:

```
"name": "person 1",
```

saving the json as "list1" and calling a print for the first element in the list1 (print(list1[0]))) prints:

```
{u'name': u'person 1',
 u'phones': {u'cell': u'666-777-8888',
             u'home': [u'000-111-2222', u'333-444-5555']}}
```

which is what I would expect seeing as how thats first "value" in this array, but how would i grab the "name": line specificity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OrderedDict` in case you are sure that your data has layout like `[{..},..]` and you don't know what the first pair in the first object is and it matters.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_json():
    file_name = raw_input("Enter name of JSON File: ")
    with open(file_name) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    return json_data
```

Then you can access first pair in first dict in the following way:

```
>>> data = get_json()
...
>>> next(iter(data[0].items())) # python 2/python 3
('name', 'person 1')
>>> data[0].items()[0] # python 2
('name', 'person 1')
>>> list(data[0].items())[0] # python 2/python 3
('name', 'person 1')
```

However, if you really care about the order you should not store your data as JSON object and use arrays instead.

`OrderedDict` and `object_pairs_hook` were added in python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

`list1[0]` is a dictionary. So, you'd simply access the value of `name` like:

```
>>> print list1[0]['name']
u'person 1'
```

Which is similar to saying:

```
>>> info = list1[0]
>>> print info['name']
u'person 1'
```